# C++ Calculate date from tm_yday and tm_year value

Tags: c++

We have a requirement to derive date from tm_yday;       day of the year (from Jan 1st) and tm_year;       years since 1900.

Can anyone help.

I have tried but no luck appreciate your help any direction would also help.

e.g value for the input 300 1900 should be 10/27/1900 where 300 is the day of the year and 1900 the year.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: If tm_yday is never allowed an illegal value (ie, cannot exceed 366, and can only be 365 on non leap years), then it is trivial to calculate what the date is given tm_yday and tm_year. Considering this--- what have you tried?

Comment: `isLeapYear = (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || year%400 == 0;` Once you know whether it is a leap year, it is trivial.

Comment: `mktime` should do it for you, if you set `tm_mon = 0`, and `tm_mday = tm_yday`. Keep in mind timezones, and such.

Comment: Upvote: I just learned that the members of `struct tm` are not all equal. `tm_mday` takes precedence over `tm_yday.` You cant give `mktime()` a struct tm partially filled in with` tm_mday` and `tm_mon`, get out a `time_t` and convert it back. It will fill a new struct with a valid tm_yday. But since `0 < tm_mday <= 31` you can't pass a `stuct tm` with only `tm_yday` and `tm_year` to `mktime()`.....

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually do this *without* involving `ctime` and the vagaries of `mktime`, which is unsuitable in this case because the value of `tm_yday` is *not* used for constructing a time (both `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` are set based on the values of the *other* fields, after adjusting them as needed).

To that end, we can simply use the following code as a starting point. It actually uses an array containing the number of days in each month, adjusting February for a leap year of course.

It then works out the month you're in by continuously subtracting the days in each month from the provided day of the year until it's less than the days in the current month.

At the end of that process, the month and days are known and we simply output the values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

// Function to detect leap year.

bool isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
    if (year % 100 == 0) return false;
    if (year % 4 == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

// Helper function for parameter checks.

int usageExit(const char *errMsg) {
    std::cerr << "*** " << errMsg << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Usage: getdate <year> <day-of-year>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Must provide two parameters.

    if (argc != 3) return usageExit("Incorrect parameter count");

    // Get (and check) year and day of year.

    char *firstBad;

    long year = std::strtol(argv[1], &firstBad, 10);
    if ((firstBad == argv[1]) || (*firstBad != '\0')) return usageExit("Year is not numeric");
    if (year < 0) return usageExit("Year is negative");
    bool leapYear = isLeapYear(year);

    long dayOfYear = std::strtol(argv[2], &firstBad, 10);
    if ((firstBad == argv[2]) || (*firstBad != '\0')) return usageExit("Day of year is not numeric");
    if ((dayOfYear < 1) || (dayOfYear > (leapYear ? 366 : 365))) return usageExit("Day of year is out of range");

    // Figure out month and day of month, from day of year.

    int daysInMonth[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (leapYear) daysInMonth[1]++;

    int month = 0;
    int daysLeft = dayOfYear;
    while (daysLeft > daysInMonth[month])
        daysLeft -= daysInMonth[month++];
    ++month;

    // Output results.

    std::cout << month << "/" << daysLeft << "/" << year << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without an iterative/branching algorithm which will make it a little more efficient.  The [algorithms are given here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).  The idea is that you can convert a triple: `{year, jan, 1}` into a serial count of days, add a number of days to that count, and then convert that sum back to a `{year, month, day}`.

[Howard Hinnant's free, open-source C++11/14/17 date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) is based on these iteration-free algorithms and offers concise and readable syntax for invoking them.  That syntax is shown below.  But first a word about `tm_yday`:

`tm_yday` is defined by the C standard as:

> days since January 1 — [0, 365]

That is, Jan 1 is day 0.  However this statement:

> e.g value for the input 300 1900 should be 10/27/1900

pegs Jan 1 as day 1.  So in the code below, `1` is subtracted from `tm_yday` to interpret Jan 1 as day 1 and `{300, 1900}` as 1900-10-27.  If this interpretation of `tm_yday` is not desired, just remove the `- 1`.

```
#include "date/date.h"

date::year_month_day
f(const std::tm& x)
{
    using namespace date;
    return sys_days{year{x.tm_year + 1900}/jan/1} + days{x.tm_yday-1};
}
```

`date::year_month_day` is a `{year, month, day}` struct with getters for each field.  This function retrieves the `tm_year` and `tm_yday` fields from a `std::tm` and converts them to a `year_month_day` using the following steps:

1. `year{x.tm_year + 1900}` converts the `tm_year` field into a type called `date::year`.  This is nothing more than just a wrapper around a `short` that means year.  It can hold values in the range [-32767, 32767].
2. The expression `year{x.tm_year + 1900}/jan/1` constructs a `date::year_month_day` for Jan 1 of the indicated year.  It simply stores the three values for year, month and day, and does no other computation.
3. `date::sys_days` is a count of days.  It is actually a `std::chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock` with a precision of `days` (as opposed to microseconds or nanoseconds).  `sys_days{...}` converts the `year_month_day` into this `time_point` (count of days), using the [`days_from_civil` algorithm](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil).
4. `date::days` is a `std::chrono::duration` with a period of 24 hours.  The expression `days{x.tm_yday-1}` converts the indicated integral expression into the `duration` type called `days`.
5. The `duration` of `days` is added to the day-precision `time_point` representing the first of the year.
6. The result of the sum is a new `time_point` holding another count of days.  This `time_point` is implicitly converted back to the return type of the function, `year_month_day`, using the [`civil_from_days` algorithm](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days).

This function can be exercised like this:

```
std::tm tm{};
tm.tm_yday = 300;
std::cout << f(tm) << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
1900-10-27
```

If you compile `f` as defined above with `clang` at any optimization higher than `-O1`, it will compile down to *branch-free* object code that references no tables.  Such code is *extremely* cache-friendly and pipeline-friendly.  For bonus points, the definition of `f` is easy on human eyes as well.